# Linux distros for Java Development

Tags: java, linux, distro

Simply, are there any Java Developer specific Linux distros?

Comment: There are no licencing issues - the OpenJDK its now 100% GPL and linux friendly.
So @Kyle is mistaken.

Comment: Your question makes almost no sense to me. Java is platform independent.

Comment: @friol: keep following the white rabbit

Comment: What does java being platform independent have to do with it? He's asking if there's a linux distro targeted at Java Developers.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A real Sun geek would chime in here about the virtues of using Solaris as a Java development platform, but I am much more ambivalent. Developing with Java is about the same on any linux distro; you are going to wind up having to install the JDK and tools of your choosing (Eclipse, Sun Studio, Tomcat, etc) so you may as well choose a distro on other criteria... perhaps how comfortable you are with it, how easy package management is, and if the look & feel suit your development habits are all big factors.

So, to answer your question more directly, a Java developer would do well with any major linux distro that they are comfortable with using in general. If you want some Java goodness out of the box, Fedora 9 and Ubuntu 8.04 have OpenJDK (and NetBeans) according to [a recent announcement](http://www.vnunet.com/vnunet/news/2215568/open-source-java-added-linux).

Answer (score 22):

Dont listen to any of these noobs suggesting one distro over another.  Java is Java and just about all distros can install java as such:

```
[package manager command to install] jdk
```

If the question was about creating RPM's, then obviously RH/CentOS/Fedora would be desirable over deb distros, source distros, or whatever other format you love.  However, due to the nature of Java, a specific distro to use is only relevant if the OP cant formulate their own opinion and must follow whatever other people are doing.

To reiterate *There is no java distro* , use whatever will have you hit the ground running.

```
// begin hypocritical personal recomendation
```

... that being said ... I *personally* use Archlinux.  Archlinux works on rolling releases so it is more likely to have a more recent JDK version then the "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sleep 6 months" distros of the world.

```
// end hypocritical personal recomendation
```

Also, I am fully prepared to get downvoted, but please, leave me above 50 so i can comment still, thanks!

Comment: Are all 6 theman* you? If you are, why did you abandon those accounts? 2 of them still have 50+ rep.

Comment: lol i never register my name.  sometimes i have to delete my cookies to test some code.  I usually develop on linux.. but have been writing some windows centric code hence the "_on_vista"

Comment: I think Archlinux is probably one of the worst choices for a Java development OS.  The distro only provides "current" package versions, so you're stuck with just Java 1.6 or craptastic gjc 1.5.  Aside from that, you're completely on your own to get Java integrated with the rest of the distro setup.

Comment: well i see you are a gentoo user.. go figure.  first point, as im sure you are aware, you can set jdk compliance level in eclipse (should that be your ide).   second, java package goes in /opt/ and then java_home gets set, what other "integration" is there?

Answer (score 10):

Solaris :)

On a serious note, there is no Linux distro dedicated to Java, so it would be about the same.

[OpenSolaris](http://opensolaris.org/os/) on the other hand (in my *very* humble experience) would be a bit faster, and you would have bonus of Dtrace as a tool. (Not that you can't find similar tools in Linux, but Dtrace should be somewhat more advanced).

Answer (score 3):

I am very heavy into Java development and I personally use Ubuntu, so I agree with Sean on this one.

The package manager allows you to easily install the various SDKs (the SUN one, or even the upcoming OpenJDK 7).

Regards,

Arjen

Answer (score 3):

I have used [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com) 8.04 and [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/) 9 with success.

For Ubuntu, the community forums were very helpful and if I remember correctly one of the repositories provided apt packages for Sun's Java6 distribution.

On Fedora 9, the Sun rpms work alright.

In either case, alternative/galternative is your friend to make sure that you point "java" and "javac" at the Sun install.  I've been using Netbeans 6.1 and Eclipse 3.4 both on Fedora 9_x64 with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

Just be careful with your distro's java installation. Most install gcj by default. For whatever reason, typing "java" into bash on most linux distros will not invoke a Sun JVM without some futzing.

Usually, there needs to be a bunch of soft-linking from /usr/local/bin -> $JDK_HOME/bin/* to get things working as I typically expect them.

Answer (score 3):

I think the motive for this question is focused on the convenience of setup: Is there any distro that has Eclipse and the full Sun Java package (JRE, JDK, and DOCS) already "baked in" so that a manual install process (and deinstall of OpenJDK) is not required?

Having an "out-of-the-box" standardized environment for a development team is a huge time saver. If you don't already have access to a Java-experienced Linux SysAdmin to guide you through the process of rolling your own automated install, learning enough to do it yourself is definitely frustrating.

Few Developers enjoy spending their time wrenching around with OS internals to get tools like Glassfish, Derby, Groovy, Grails, GWT, etc. all working together. They prefer to go directly to writing code and inventing stuff inside a personal sandbox that exploits a pre-existing ecosystem of built-in services...

On the deployment side, having a common Linux install that requires no system-level configuration for end-users except for installing their favorite Java applications' .JAR file would be another big win.

There's definitely a market for someone to provide this, but most folks are simply gritting their teeth and doing it for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Either SUSE or RH, both have official support. 
http://www.java.com/en/download/help/5000010500.xml

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of a Java-developer-specific Linux distro.

If you need a Linux distro for work purposes (not for personal home use) then the choice of distro is not really affected by the fact that you need to install a JDK, but other factors:

- how quickly can it be installed?
- how easy is it to maintain (updates etc)?
- how fully-featured is it out-of-the-box?
- how well supported is it? (commercial support if you need it, otherwise how good is community support?)

My suggestions for work-purposes: Ubuntu and Suse have been good for me.  I have no experience with the others mentioned (eg: Fedora).

Basically, get a distro that "just plain works".  Everything you need (JDK, IDE, etc) will almost certainly be easily installed from there.

Answer (score 1):

I had a pleasant experience with Mandriva power pack 2008. Select something like development->"java tools" and everything is installed for you.

Everything being Sun JRE, JDK, and eclispe.

Solaris did install a 64bit kernel by default though.....

Answer (score 1):

Latest Ubuntu version. It is easy enough and have packaged Sun Java, Eclipse, NetBeans, GlassFish, TomCat and other Java development related software so you have no worries installing and configuring it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any of the distro available bcoz dere is no linux distro specifically for java development. Personally I have worked on RHEL 5, Fedora 9, Mandriva with considerable success.

Working on java is same on any linux distribution after the installation of jdk, tomcat, eclipse, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick Stinemates mentioned, Gentoo is an excellent distro for developing Java.  It is one of the few Distros that I know of that has a very active Java maintainer group and almost everything that people use regularly is already packaged.

Be warned, Gentoo is not a drop dead simple distro to use Ubuntu -- you have to understand a bit about how the OS works -- but it does provide an excellent developerment environment.

Answer (score 0):

The distro which is most developer friendly, in my opinion, is [Gentoo](http://gentoo.org). Since you compile everything from scratch, you choose exactly what makes up your system. Java can be installed very easily, so you could potentially just have a [window environment](http://xfce.org) and Java installed (aside from the standard tool chain.)

Comment: i would upvote if i could because I understand what your saying, but I would downvote you cause you linked to xfce and not dwm :)

Comment: dwm is pretty baller :) i'm an awesome fan now

Comment: Installing a Gentoo system from scratch is INTENSE! :)
It was a pretty fun experience, and I'm a Windows fanboy!

Comment: It gets better the second time :)

Comment: Agreed, much better the second time.

Answer (score 0):

For a start: most -if not all- linux distribution allow you to "easily" install (that is: using the distribution's package manager) jdk's and jre's. The choice essentialy is more about what aspect of the distribution is most relevant to your personal taste.

Personnaly, I've come to value overall distribution stability (as in: upgrades to the base system are more or less guaranteed-not-to-hose-my-workstation-one-day-before-delivery-date) more, which made me stick with debian for the past few years.

The price to pay for that is either "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sleep 6 months" as theman_on_vista points out, or just install relevant stuff yourself in /opt. After all, installing some jdk's, maven or ant and eclipse|netbeans is easy enough (hell, there even is documentation somewhere I'm sure :) )

Answer (score 0):

Oracle JVM from their website is going to have the same speed on debian, archlinux and slackware (and probably their derivatives). Your best bet is to tweak the JVM arguments for the web servers/IDEs you might be using. Remember that java for x64 architectures will consume more memory due to [larger native pointers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_performance), so you would do well to tweak your heap size accordingly. Especially if you don't want your server to stop with an OutOfMemoryError exception.

Answer (score 0):

if you use ubuntu or other debian family you can try this command

```sh
sudo apt-get install default-jdk default-jre
```

Answer (score -3):

While not *really* a distribution, there is a virtual machine available for [Tomcat](http://virtualappliances.net/products/tomcat.php).  It could be adapted pretty easily for other Java based deployments (available for several virtualization technologies).

There are also several Java App Server VMs available from [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/) (VMWare only, of course).